# How do you call static classes in a Nunit test (c#)

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I can not find a way to call my static class in Nunit. I can't change the class to a non static class because I need to test this for a assignment.

This is my test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Microwave;

namespace Microwave.Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

        }

        [Test]
        public void DontKnowTheNameYet()
        {
            var microwave = new StateEngine();
            /*When the open state is open */
            var currInput = "IsOpen";
            /*The OpenDoor event should be triggerd*/
            /*Message should say "Door is Open*/
            Assert.Contains("Door is open");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code i am trying to test:

```
namespace Microwave
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using Models;

    /// <summary>
    ///     The state engine.
    /// </summary>
    public static class StateEngine
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets or sets the current state.
        /// </summary>
        private static Enum CurrentState { get; set; } = State.Closed;

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        ///     The microwave engine.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="currInput">
        ///     The current state of the microwave input.
        /// </param>
        public static void MicrowaveEngine(MicrowaveData currInput)
        {
            switch (CurrentState)
            {
                case State.Closed:
                    if (currInput.IsOpen)
                    {
                        // If the door is open
                        CurrentState = State.Open;

                        RaiseOpenDoor();
                        RaiseShowMessage($"Door is open");
                    }
                    else if (currInput.Time > 0)
                    {
                        CurrentState = State.Ready;
                        RaiseSetReady();
                        RaiseSetLightReady();
                    }
                    else if (currInput.IsStartClicked)
                    {
                        // If start is clicked and door is closed
                        RaiseShowMessage($"Can not start when the door is open");
                        currInput.IsStartClicked = false;
                    }

                    break;
                case State.Open:
                    if (currInput.IsOpen == false && currInput.Time > 0)
                    {
                        // If the door is closed and the timer has been set
                        CurrentState = State.Ready;

                        RaiseCloseDoor();
                        RaiseSetReady();
                        RaiseSetLightReady();
                    }
                    else if (!currInput.IsOpen)
                    {
                        // If door is closed
                        CurrentState = State.Closed;
                        RaiseCloseDoor();
                    }
                    else if (currInput.IsStartClicked)
                    {
                        // If start is pressed
                        RaiseShowMessage("I can't do that like this senpai!");
                        currInput.IsStartClicked = false;
                    }

                    break;
                case State.Cooking:
                    // Door closed and timer 0
                    if (currInput.Time <= 0)
                    {
                        CurrentState = State.Closed;

                        currInput.IsStartClicked = false;
                        RaiseSetLightInactive();
                        RaiseShowMessage("Your meal is ready");
                    }
                    else if (currInput.IsOpen && currInput.Time > 0)
                    {
                        // If the door is open and timer not 0
                        CurrentState = State.Open;

                        RaiseOpenDoor();
                        currInput.IsStartClicked = false;
                        RaiseSetLightInactive();
                        RaisePauseTimer();
                        RaiseShowMessage($"Close the door en press start to resume cooking");
                    }
                    else if (!currInput.IsStartClicked)
                    {
                        // If the start is clicked off
                        currInput.IsStartClicked = true;
                        RaiseShowMessage("Can not start without a time set");
                    }

                    break;
                case State.Ready:
                    if (currInput.IsOpen)
                    {
                        // If the door is open
                        RaiseShowMessage("The door is forcefully closed");
                        currInput.IsOpen = false;
                    }
                    else if (currInput.IsStartClicked)
                    {
                        // If start is pressed
                        CurrentState = State.Cooking;

                        RaiseStartTimer();
                        RaiseSetLightActive();
                        RaiseShowMessage($"The cooking started");
                    }
                    else if (currInput.Time <= 0)
                    {
                        CurrentState = State.Closed;

                        RaiseShowMessage($"The microwave stopped");
                        RaiseSetLightInactive();
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("ERROR: Not existing state");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the open door event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseOpenDoor()
        {
            OpenDoor?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the closed door event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseCloseDoor()
        {
            CloseDoor?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the set ready event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseSetReady()
        {
            SetReady?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the show message event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">
        ///     The message to display.
        /// </param>
        private static void RaiseShowMessage(string message)
        {
            ShowMessage?.Invoke(null, message);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the start timer event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseStartTimer()
        {
            StartTimer?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the pause timer event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaisePauseTimer()
        {
            PauseTimer?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the set light inactive event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseSetLightInactive()
        {
            SetLightInactive?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the set light ready event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseSetLightReady()
        {
            SetLightReady?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Raise the set light active event.
        /// </summary>
        private static void RaiseSetLightActive()
        {
            SetLightActive?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        #region Attributes

        /// <summary>
        ///     The state.
        /// </summary>
        private enum State
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     The closed.
            /// </summary>
            Closed,

            /// <summary>
            ///     The open.
            /// </summary>
            Open,

            /// <summary>
            ///     The cooking.
            /// </summary>
            Cooking,

            /// <summary>
            ///     The ready.
            /// </summary>
            Ready
        }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        ///     The open the door event.
        ///     Open the door of the microwave.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler OpenDoor;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The close the door event.
        ///     Close the door of the microwave.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler CloseDoor;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The set light inactive event.
        ///     Set the light to the inactive color.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler SetLightInactive;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The set light ready event.
        ///     Set the light to the ready color.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler SetLightReady;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The set light active event.
        ///     Set the light to the active color.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler SetLightActive;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The set ready event.
        ///     Show that the microwave is ready.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler SetReady;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The start timer event.
        ///     Start the timer on the microwave.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler StartTimer;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The pause timer event.
        ///     Start the timer on the microwave.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler PauseTimer;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The show message event.
        ///     Show a message in the message box.
        /// </summary>
        public static event EventHandler<string> ShowMessage;

        #endregion
    }

    namespace Models
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        /// <summary>
        ///     The model for all the current input of the microwave.
        /// </summary>
        public class MicrowaveData : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region Attributes
            
            /// <summary>
            ///     The time.
            /// </summary>
            private int _time;
            
            /// <summary>
            ///     The is open clicked.
            /// </summary>
            private bool _isOpen;

            /// <summary>
            ///     The is start clicked.
            /// </summary>
            private bool _isStartClicked;

            #endregion

            #region Properties

            /// <summary>
            ///     Gets or sets the time.
            /// </summary>
            public int Time
            {
                get => _time;

                set
                {
                    if (_time == value) return;

                    _time = value;

                    // Send the event for this property
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Time");

                    // Send events for properties that depend on this property
                    RaisePropertyChanged("TimeWithMinutes");
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the door is opened.
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsOpen
            {
                get => _isOpen;
                set
                {
                    if (_isOpen == value) return;

                    _isOpen = value;

                    // Send the event for this property
                    RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpenClicked");

                    // Send events for properties that depend on this property
                    RaisePropertyChanged("OpenButtonText");
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the start is clicked.
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsStartClicked
            {
                get => _isStartClicked;
                set
                {
                    if (_isStartClicked == value) return;

                    _isStartClicked = value;

                    // Send the event for this property
                    RaisePropertyChanged("IsStartClicked");

                    // Send events for properties that depend on this property
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region Events

            /// <summary>
            ///     the event that is send when a property is changed.
            /// </summary>
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            #endregion

            #region EventSenders

            /// <summary>
            ///     send the <see cref="PropertyChanged" /> event.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="propertyName">The property name.</param>
            protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

They are in seperate projects but i linked them like this, this is in the testing project where the test is written:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Console" Version="3.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MicrowaveTesting\MicrowaveTesting.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: `var microwave = new StateEngine()` - you can't create an instance of a static class.

Comment: You cannnot instantiate static classes. You should access them directly: var state = StateEngine.CurrentState;

Comment: @user3026017 If i do that it gives me the error: 'StateEngine.CurrentState' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Because it is private...

Comment: I think the focus of this has changed a bit.  As the others have said, you can call the static class, you just can't access a private method from another class.  You have to ask yourself why do you want this to be private?  It looks like you made it private because you want your MicrowaveEngine method to control its state, which is fine.  In that case you should have a public get and a private set perhaps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility